# 500 internal server error with Mobx

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobx

Whenever I try to import observer from `mobx-react`the app crashes with a 500 error code.
Did I install/configured mobx wrong?

1- `npm i mobx mobx-react --save`

2- `npm i babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy
    babel-preset-react-native-stage-0 --save-dev`

3- Inside the root folder's .babelrc:

```
`{'presets': ['react-native'],'plugins': ['transform-decorators-legacy']}`
```

4-  Package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-native": "^0.40.0",
    "mobx": "^3.0.2",
    "mobx-react": "^4.1.0"
}
```

**Store.js:**

```
import { observable, computed } from 'mobx'

class GetFoo {
    @observable Foo = "bar"

    root() {
        return this.Foo
    }
}

let store = new GetFoo()

export default store
```

**App component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
    Text,
    View
} from 'react-native'
import NetProvider from './config/netInfo'
import { observer } from 'mobx-react'

@observer
export default class AppRoot extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props)
        return(
            <NetProvider>
                <View>
                    <Text>Hi</Text>
                </View>
            </NetProvider>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it show any error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `mobx-react/native` for React Native:

```
import { observer } from 'mobx-react/native'
```